# Why can I not add a FileTransferProgress handler while the session is open?

Tags: powershell, winscp, powershell-5.0, winscp-net

I have a *very* basic function so sync a remote folder to local. This is working well with a `FileTransferred` handler and I wanted to add a `FileTransferProgress` to the mix and then use `Write-Progress`. However I cannot get to that since it appears I cannot add a `FileTransferProgress` handler while the session is open.

```
function Sync-RemoteToLocalFolder{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [WinSCP.Session]$Session,

        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [string]$RemotePath="/",

        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory)]
        [string]$LocalPath
    )

    $fileTransferedEvent = {Invoke-FileTransferredEvent $_}

    # Determine how many files are in this folder tree
    $fileCount = (Get-WinSCPItems -Session $Session -RemotePath $RemotePath | Where-Object{$_.IsDirectory -eq $false}).Count

    $fileProgressEvent = {Invoke-FileProgressEvent $_ $fileCount}

    try{
        # Set the file transfer event handler
        Write-Verbose "Setting Transfered handler"
        $session.add_FileTransferred($fileTransferedEvent)

        # Set the transfer progress handler
        Write-Verbose "Setting Progress handler"
        $Session.add_FileTransferProgress($fileProgressEvent)

        # Sync the directories
        Write-Verbose "Syncronizing '$LocalPath' with '$RemotePath'"
        $synchronizationResult = $session.SynchronizeDirectories([WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, $LocalPath, $RemotePath, $False)

        # Check the result for errors
        $synchronizationResult.Check()

        # Remove the handlers from the session
        $session.remove_FileTransferred($fileTransferedEvent)
        $Session.remove_FileTransferProgress($fileProgressEvent)

    }catch [Exception]{
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
```

If I run this, with an open `$session` passed then I get the message `Sync-RemoteToLocalFolder : Session is already opened`. I found that odd since I added a different kind of handler on the fly but these could function differently. So I can comment out the two lines about the `FileTransferProgress` and the above function works as much as I want it to (there are some logic flaws but they exist outside of this issue e.g. I need to update the scriptblock for `$fileProgressEvent`).

Why can I not add a `FileTransferProgress` handler while the session is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation of the implementation.

Nothing you can do about it.

---

It's [documented now](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress):

> The event has to be subscribed before calling [`Open`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_open).

---

As a workaround, you can introduce a flag in the event handler, to turn it off.

Comment: I figured. I appreciate the info and docs update. I never thought of adding a flag so that would works